# Getting wrong coordinate from Cesium-DrawHelper shape created event

Tags: terrain, cesiumjs

i am using cesium with drawHelper plugin on GWT (Cesium Terrain Server for terrain). i am drawing shapes(marker , polyline , polygon..) to my 3d map.
I can draw shapes to the map with exact coordinates where my mouse is pointing but  when i change the angle of camera look , i cannot draw shapes where my mouse pointing because i am getting wrong coordinates and this leads to draw my shapes on wrong coordinates.
(i get coordinates from DrawHelpers shape create event for instance 'markerCreated' returns position)

Comment: I think this is similar to [navigating on cesium terrain map, corrupts position of graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370129/navigating-on-cesium-terrain-map-corrupts-position-of-graphics/33372453#33372453).

Comment: Actually its not because it was about draping and pinning shapes on terrain , this is about getting wrong mouse position .

Comment: Sure, but it's the same root cause, though: Picking the ellipsoid instead of picking the terrain.  That's why switching to the other pick function, in your solution below, works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with editing DrawHelper.js , 
it was getting position with scene.camera.pickEllipsoid function  , i changed it with creating a ray and picking position via globe.pick. Code :

```
var cartesian = scene.camera.pickEllipsoid(movement.position,ellipsoid)
```

Replaced it with

```
var ray = scene.camera.getPickRay(movement.position);
var pickedPosition = scene.globe.pick(ray,scene);
if(pickedPosition){
markers.addBillBoard(pickedPosition);
_self.stopDrawing();
options.callback(pickedPosition);
```

Adding marker on terrain to the coordinates which pointing from mouse fixed like this...

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you so much to share your solution.