# Cesium - using camera to scale a polygon to match Lat-Lon positions while zoom-in/zoom-out

Tags: javascript, node.js, camera, terrain, cesiumjs

I am struggling with camera functionality that (I think) would provide a way to **force my polygon to stick to the top of my house** on zoom-out, zoom-in, and rotation (or camera move).

This question follows an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36142788/1735836) that was resolved.  Now I need a little help resolving my next issue.

The sample code I am trying to follow is located in [the gold standard that appears to be baked into the existing camera controller here](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.19/Source/Scene/ScreenSpaceCameraController.js#L696-L711).

**pickGlobe** is executed with the parameters of the viewer, the correct mousePosition in world coordinates and a result parameter, which I don't care about right now.  **scene.pickPosition** takes the c2position (**Cartesian2**) and should return the scratchDepthIntersection (**Cartesian3**).  Instead, the returned value is **undefined**.

**Here is my code:**

```
function clickAction(click) {
    var cartesian = scene.camera.pickEllipsoid(click.position, ellipsoid);
    if (cartesian) {
        var setCartographic = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);
        collection.latlonalt.push(
            Cesium.Math.toDegrees(setCartographic.latitude).toFixed(15),
            Cesium.Math.toDegrees(setCartographic.longitude).toFixed(15),
            Cesium.Math.toDegrees(setCartographic.height).toFixed(15)
        );
        lla.push(Cesium.Math.toDegrees(setCartographic.longitude), Cesium.Math.toDegrees(setCartographic.latitude));
        if (lla.length >= 4) {
            console.log((lla.length / 2) + ' Points Added');
        }
        enableDoubleClick();
        enableDraw();

        testMe(click.position);  <--------------------- straight from the mouse click
    }
}

var pickedPosition;
var scratchZoomPickRay = new Cesium.Ray();
var scratchPickCartesian = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
function testMe(c2MousePosition) {  <--------------------- straight from the mouse click
    if (Cesium.defined(scene.globe)) { 
        if(scene.mode !== Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D) {
            pickedPosition = pickGlobe(viewer, c2MousePosition, scratchPickCartesian);
        } else {
            pickedPosition = camera.getPickRay(c2MousePosition, scratchZoomPickRay).origin;
        }
    }
}

var pickGlobeScratchRay = new Cesium.Ray();
var scratchRayIntersection = new Cesium.Cartesian3();    
var c2position = new Cesium.Cartesian2();
function pickGlobe(viewer, c2MousePosition, result) {   <--------------------- straight from the mouse click
    c2position = c2MousePosition;   <--------------------- setting to Cartesian2

    var scratchDepthIntersection = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
    if (scene.pickPositionSupported) {
        scratchDepthIntersection = scene.pickPosition(c2MousePosition);  <--------------------- neither works!
    }

}
```

**Here are my variables:**

[image]

**Here is the result:**

[image]

Here are my questions to get this code working:

**1. Why is scratchDepthIntersection not getting set?**  c2position is a Cartesian2 and c2MousePosition is straight from the mouse.click.position and scratchDepthIntersection is a new Cartesian3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct value for `mousePosition` is a `Cartesian2` containing window coordinates, not a `Cartesian3`.  Such mouse coordinates usually come from a callback from `Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler`, but can also be constructed from native JavaScript mouse/touch events.

If you inspect the contents of `mousePosition`, you should find `x` and `y` values in window pixel coordinates.

I see you edited the question to include the contents of `mousePosition`, and it looks like the mouse coordinates have already been converted into ellipsoid `Cartesian3` coordinates, which will prevent this code from working.  You want original mouse coordinates going directly into `scene.pickPosition` for this to work.

Comment: Well, CRAP!  It worked once.  Can I just take the click.position?  Or do I have to declare it as a Cartesian2()?  They look the same.  I've tried it both ways.  Rebooted my machine.....I am ready to scream.  I'll post code again.

Comment: Sounds like you're close.  Yes, if Cesium gives you a `click.position`, that is already the correct data structure to pass in here.

Comment: Yay!  I got it working then it stopped working then I got it working again and pushed it to git!  Good thing, because it stopped working again.  So I deleted the application and pulled it back down from git and it started working again.  Temperamental project!

Comment: Hey emackey!  I have a new question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/36271816/1735836