# Cesium - drawing polygon using camera Lat-Lon-Alt positions

Tags: javascript, node.js, camera, terrain, cesiumjs

This question is related to these two:

1. [Cesium how to scale a polygon to match Lat-Lon positions while zoom-in/zoom-out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35929240/1735836)
2. [Cesium - using camera to scale a polygon to match Lat-Lon positions while zoom-in/zoom-out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36223668/1735836)

The sample code I am following to get lat-lon-alt positions from the camera is located in the [gold standard that appears to be baked into the existing camera controller](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.19/Source/Scene/ScreenSpaceCameraController.js#L696-L711).  With this code I can retrieve lat-lon-alt positions from the distance of the camera to get values that are almost exact to the original lat-lon position selected and a height above the surface of the earth.  Perfect!

**All examples and documentation show polygon creation using degrees or points from degrees.**

Now what?  Maybe I'm missing something but the intent I thought was to be able to create the polygon using specific x, y, z coordinates so the polygon would "stick" to the top of my house on zoom-in, zoom-out, and camera movement.  Now that I have those values, what is the secret to drawing the polygon with those values?

FYI, these are the value I currently have:

[image]

---

**=========================NEW INFORMATION===========================**

The code for the redPolygon works:

```
var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                        -115.0, 32.0,
                                                        -102.0, 31.0,
                                                        -102.0, 35.0,
                                                        -102.0, 35.0]),
        material : Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});

viewer.flyTo(redPolygon);
```

The code for the bluePolygon does not work:

```
var bluePolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Blue polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        //hierarchy: collection.latlonalt,
        hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromArray(collection.latlonalt),
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE
    }
});

viewer.flyTo(bluePolygon);
```

If I use `hierarchy: collection.latlonalt,` I receive the following error:

[image]

So I changed the code to `hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromArray(collection.latlonalt),` where collection.latlonalt is my Cartesian3 array:

[image]

But nothing gets drawn.  No errors.  This is what I see in the console:

[image]

Just for test, I tried adding a z position to the redPolygon and changing .fromDegreesArray to .fromArray like this:

```
var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromArray([-115.0, 37.0, 10.0,
                                                 -115.0, 32.0, 10.0,
                                                 -102.0, 31.0, 10.0,
                                                 -102.0, 35.0, 10.0,
                                                 -102.0, 35.0, 10.0]),
        material : Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});

viewer.flyTo(redPolygon);
```

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cesium has helper functions like [`Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html#.fromDegreesArray) that are used by the [Polygon Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Polygon.html&label=All), but, these helper functions are not needed now that you've got your hands on actual Cartesian3 values.

For example, the polygon demo code looks like this:

```
var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                        -115.0, 32.0,
                                                        -107.0, 33.0,
                                                        -102.0, 31.0,
                                                        -102.0, 35.0]),
        material : Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});
```

In the above code, `fromDegreesArray` in this case just takes a list of 5 lot/lan value pairs, and converts them into a JavaScript array of 5 instances of the `Cartesian3` class.  This array of 5 Cartesian3s is then stored as the value of `hierarchy` in the polygon definition.  If you inspect that definition at runtime, you'll find the original lon/lat values have been discarded, replaced by the actual Cartesian3s, thanks to the helper function.

So in your code, you'll need an array of Cartesian3s that the user has clicked on thus far.  This starts as the empty array, and you'll need to gather at least three clicks, converting each click into a Cartesian3 as you've shown works in your question above, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) that value into the array.  Once the array has accumulated 3 or more clicks, you can then pass that array as the `hierarchy` field of the polygon definition.

In this manner, you've avoided calling `fromDegreesArray` because your click handler is doing the more detailed work of gathering an exact Cartesian position per click.  This gathering has to happen at the time of each click, in case the camera is moved between clicks.  So, the array "in progress" has to survive between clicks, until all the clicks have been gathered and a polygon can be created.

**EDIT**: Here's an example of the code structure I'm trying to describe.  I don't show the actual click handlers here, since you seem to have Cartesian3 values coming out of your mouse clicks already.  Instead, I show three such values being used to create a polygon.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

// Create an empty array of click positions at the start.
var clickPositions = [];

// When the first mouse click is received, convert to Cartesian3, and push it into the array.
var click1 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(-2155350.2, -4622163.4, 3817393.1);
clickPositions.push(click1);

// Later, more mouse clicks are received and pushed into the array.
var click2 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(-2288079.8, -4906803.1, 3360431.4);
clickPositions.push(click2);

var click3 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(-1087466.8, -5116129.4, 3637866.9);
clickPositions.push(click3);

// Finally, draw the polygon.
var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : clickPositions,
        material : Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});
```

Notice nothing happens to `clickPositions` when it's assigned to `hierarchy`.  The array of Cartesian3 values is already in the form needed by Cesium here.

Comment: Hey, emacky!  Maybe I'm still doing something wrong but it's not drawing.  See my edit below `NEW INFORMATION`

Comment: Hi Miss Lucy, I added a new code block to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!  I saw where "This error is almost always caused by a NaN or undefined value" in several other answers.  At some point I started to wonder if I needed to add points but I hadn't gotten that for in my testing.  This is perfect.